# regular expression for date in any format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

regular expression for date in any format in javascript

The format includes: dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/dd/mm or dd-yy-mmmm or ddmmyyyy like so on.....

can any one help please??

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Comment: Regular Expressions are highly inappropriate for this sort of thing. There are too many rules (1 to 31 unless the next block is one of these numbers in which case it is 30 unless it is 2 in which case it is 28 except in a leap year, etc, etc). Use a proper date parsing library.

Comment: What sort of date is dd-yy-mmmm?!

Comment: How would _you_ parse the date `01/04/2012`? January 4th or April 1st? How _could_ a regular expression parse it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "perfect" parse but I would suggest using something like [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for handling dates in javascript. It can handle a number of parsing routines with a wide variety of format support.

Answer (score 0):

Reg Ex for dates with leap year consideration. Wrote it for as3, but since js and as3 are both derivative of ECMAScript, it should work fine in JS too.

**Change # in the reg ex with your desired date separator. For a global separator replace # with (/|-|.)**

For DD-MM-YYYY format

```
^(?:31#(?:(?:0[13578])|(?:1[02]))#)|(?:(?:29|30)#(?:(?:0[1,3-9])|(?:1[0-2]))#)(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$|^(?:29#02#(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1\d)|(?:2[0-8]))#(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))#(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$
```

For MM-DD-YYYY format

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])#31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])#(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2#29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))#(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Tests with performance.

```
29-02-2000 ---> true
millis 2
29-02-2006 ---> false
millis 0
29-02-2001 ---> false
millis 0
30-02-2000 ---> false
millis 0
31-11-2000 ---> false
millis 0
29-13-2000 ---> false
millis 0
31-11-2000 ---> false
millis 0
31-07-2000 ---> true
millis 0
31-08-2000 ---> true
millis 1
31-12-2000 ---> true
millis 0
30-11-2011 ---> true
millis 0
17-07-2011 ---> true
millis 0
04-10-1987 ---> true
millis 0
01-01-1900 ---> true
millis 0
24-05-88 ---> false
millis 0
24-05-88 ---> false
millis 0
29-12-2011 ---> true
millis 0
31-12-2000 ---> true
millis 0
1-1-2010 ---> false
millis 0
1-1-99 ---> false
millis 0
1-01-99 ---> false
millis 0
01-1-99 ---> false
millis 0
```

For various formats, modify date seperators reg ex and ordering.